# Allow Content Security Policy For Iframe With data:text/html

Tags: html, content-security-policy

I'm trying to use iframe with `data:text/html`. My iframe tag is:

```html
<iframe id="preview" class="preview" src="data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3Cscript%20src%3D%22https%3A//cdnjs.cloudfla..."> </iframe>
```

Normally it was working in localhost. But when I host it I got this error:

```
"data" connections are blocked
This content has been blocked. Contact the site owner to fix the problem.

ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CSP
```

So I try CSP tag in HTML to allow all;

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; img-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline';">
```

But still not working. How can I fix it?